# Can a mechanical engineer degree holder with Aerospace industry experience apply for Australian PR?

Tags: resident-permit, indian-citizens, australian-citizens

My brother is a Mechanical Engineering degree holder working in a PSU in India in the aerospace field as Manager, and has around 12 yrs experience. He's looking for migration to Australia.

1. Considering that the field he is working is Defence-related, is there any scope for jobs in the same field in Australia?
2. How difficult would it be for security clearance from both countries?
3. Would he have to look for a job in different field?